# How to setup Power BI licenses

Tags: powerbi

My organization has bought Power BI licenses, **Pro** licenses for developers and **Premium** for standard user to view reports and dashboards.

Now it is my responsibility to configure these licenses so users can view developed reports.

Considering I have limited Power BI configuration experience I am stuck at the moment.

I have published my report and configured data gateway.

I am stuck at the point of sharing the report with other users.

When other users try to connect to Power BI cloud they get invalid password (all users the same)

Which made me think it is applying licenses to these users.

I am not sure how to do that and other resources such as this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-share-dashboards)

Tells me to add them when I click on Share Report which does not work the same way the link shows

The link shows this screen:

[image]

While I get this one:

[image]

How can I give users premium permission to Power BI

Comment: When you buy Power BI Premium, there is a ream of documentation on how to set this up. It will have been emailed to all the global administrators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing Power BI reports happens in the **browser**, i.e. in the **Power BI Service**. Your second screenshot is from **Power BI desktop**, taken while publishing a report to the Service. After publishing the report, you need to go to the Power BI Service (app.PowerBI.com) and from there you can share the report with users.